# Derivative of $y = x^{7 \sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus

What is the derivative of $y = x^{7 \sin(x)}$?

Using the fact that the derivative of $x^a$ is $x^a \ln(a)$ and chain rule, I got $7x^{7 \sin(x)}\ln(7\sin(x))\cos(x)$ as the answer. However, the answer was $7x^{7\sin(x)}(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}+\ln(x)\cos(x))$ instead, where they found it by taking the logarithm of both sides. I get why that solution works but why is mine wrong?

Comment: First of all, the derivative of $x^a$ is not what you wrote. You confuse it with $a^x$. But anyway, you can't simply replace a constant $a$ by an expression that depends on $x$.

Comment: oops sorry, I meant $a^x$

Comment: Hint: write $y=e^{7\sin(x)log(x)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ is a constant then $\frac{d}{dx} x^a = ax^{a-1}= \frac{ax^a}{x}$ not $x^a \ln(a)$

Similarly if $b$ is a constant then $\frac{d}{dx} b^x = b^x \ln(b)$

and $\frac{d}{dx} b^{7\sin(x)} = b^{7\sin(x)}\ln(b)7\cos(x)$

so $\frac{d}{dx} x^{7\sin(x)} =   \frac{7\sin(x)x^{7\sin(x)} }{x} + x^{7\sin(x)}\ln(x)7\cos(x) $ $= 7x^{7\sin(x)}\left( \frac{\sin(x) }{x} + \ln(x)\cos(x)\right)$

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the derivative of $x^a$ with $a^x$. In this case use $\ln y = 7 \sin (x) \cdot \ln x$ and differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ get the desired

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $x^a$ is $a x^{a-1}$ (for $a$ independent of $x$) , and the derivative of $a^x$ is $a^x \ln(a)$ (again , $a$ needs to be independent of $x$).

In your case you have $x^{7 \sin(x)}$. Neither the base nor the exponent are independent of $x$, so those rules don't apply.

To take the derivative properly, take the derivative wrt each occurrence of $x$ separately, pretending all the other occurrences are constants. Then add them (to prove this works, apply the multivariable chain rule to $f \circ \Delta$, where $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the desired function and $\Delta : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is $x \rightarrow (x, ... x)$) .

$\frac{d}{dx} x^{7 sin(a)} = 7 \sin(a) x^{7 \sin(a)-1}$, and $\frac{d}{dx} a^{7 \sin(x)} =  a^{7 \sin(x)} \ln(a) 7 \cos(x)$.

Now add them, $7 \sin(x) x^{7 \sin(x) -1} + x^{7 \sin(x)} \ln(x) 7 \cos(x)$